# Vue Draggable Recursive / Nested Dragging Weird Behavior

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuedraggable

**This question will be bountied as soon as I can, so a big rep reward coming to someone!**

EDIT: One more layer to this issue I noticed, The lowest level children when I try to drag it somewhere else it doesn't work, acts like it will but goes back where it was (i.e it's children are empty). But when I drag the parent of a child somewhere else it does one of the following:

1. Moves the parent and it's parent somewhere else where I drag it, but leaves the child where it was i.e
   [image]
   Initial state on a refresh

[image]
After I drag col-2 to container-1

or

2. Moves the child into the container where I dragged the parent to but leaves the parent where it was i.e
   [image]
   Initial state on a refresh

[image]
After dragging col-2 into col-1

#### Original Post

Hey guys, been building a landing page builder and decided vue-draggable would be a nice addition. That said after 3 days of headaches trying to make this work I'm at a loss. So far I've followed the nested example guide which has been KINDA working, in addition, I followed an issue about the nested guide on here adding an emitter to the children for proper updates. Now my getters and setters are firing BUT I'm still having a problem dragging elements(see the video)

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/ZMiyi8LEcI73nye1ZN

As you can see when I drag stuff around it's strange behavior:

Example cases:

- When I drag col 2 label into col 1 it moves the children inside into
  col one, does not change col 2s place
- When I drag paragraph label
  anywhere it will not move, shows like it will but when I release
  nothing happens
- If I drag row 1 from the original starting state you
  saw in the gif into the paragraph I end up with the following:

[image]

Just 3 sample cases, references:
https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-with-vmodel
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/701#issuecomment-686187071

my code creating these results:

component-renderer.vue **(THERE'S A NOTE IN HERE TO READ)**

```
  <draggable
    v-bind="dragOptions"
    :list="list"
    :value="value"
    style="position: relative; border: 1px solid red"
    :tag="data.tagName"
    :class="data.attributes.class + ` border border-danger p-3`"
    @input="emitter"
    @change="onChange" //NOTE: I've tried setting the group here to row instead of in the computed prop below, didn't work
  >
    <slot></slot>

    <component-renderer
      v-for="el in realValue"
      :key="el.attributes.id"
      :list="el.children"
      :data="el"
      :child="true"
      @change="onChange"
    >
      <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: red">{{
        `${el.tagName} - ${el.attributes.id}`
      }}</span>

      {{ el.textNode }}
    </component-renderer>
  </draggable>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  name: "ComponentRenderer",
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  props: {
    data: {
      required: false,
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
    value: {
      required: false,
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },
    list: {
      required: false,
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    },
    child: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    dragOptions() {
      return {
        animation: 0,
        disabled: false,
        ghostClass: "row",
        group: "row",
      };
    },
    realValue() {
      return this.value ? this.value : this.list;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    emitter(value) {
      this.$emit("input", value);
    },
    onChange: function () {
      if (this.child === true) {
        this.$emit("change");
      } else {
        this.emitter(this.value);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

PageEditor.vue:

```
  <div id="wysiwyg-page-editor">
    <ChargeOverNavBar />
    <div class="editor">
      <ComponentRenderer v-model="elements" :data="elements[0]" />
    </div>
    <ChargeOverFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChargeOverNavBar from "@/components/ChargeOverNavBar";
import ChargeOverFooter from "@/components/ChargeOverFooter";
import InlineEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline";
import ComponentRenderer from "@/components/module-editor/ComponentRenderer";

export default {
  name: "PageEditor",
  components: {
    ComponentRenderer,
    ChargeOverFooter,
    ChargeOverNavBar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: InlineEditor,
      editorConfig: {},

      activeSection: null,

      page: {},

      panels: {
        pageProperties: true,
        seoProperties: true,
        sectionProperties: false,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    elements: {
      get() {
        console.log("getter");

        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.editor.editorData));
      },
      set(value) {
        console.log("setter");
        this.$store.dispatch("setEditor", value);
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@use "../assets/scss/components/PageEditor";
</style>
```

editor.js(store module):

```
  state: {
    editorData: [],
    editorLoading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    SAVE_EDITOR(state, data) {
      state.editorData = data;
    },
    TOGGLE_EDITOR_LOAD(state, busy) {
      state.editorLoading = busy;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setEditor({ commit }, data) {
      commit("SAVE_EDITOR", data);
    },
    loadEditor({ commit }) {
      commit("TOGGLE_EDITOR_LOAD", true);

      //TODO: Change me to read API DATA
      let fakeData = [
        {
          tagName: "section",
          attributes: {
            id: "section-1",
            class: "test",
          },
          children: [
            {
              tagName: "div",
              attributes: {
                id: "container-1",
                class: "container",
              },
              children: [
                {
                  tagName: "div",
                  attributes: {
                    id: "row-1",
                    class: "row",
                  },
                  children: [
                    {
                      tagName: "div",
                      attributes: {
                        id: "col-1",
                        class: "col",
                      },
                      children: [],
                    },
                    {
                      tagName: "div",
                      attributes: {
                        id: "col-2",
                        class: "col",
                      },
                      children: [
                        {
                          tagName: "p",
                          attributes: {
                            id: "p-1",
                            class: "p",
                          },
                          textNode: "This is my paragraph",
                          children: [],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
      commit("SAVE_EDITOR", fakeData);
      commit("TOGGLE_EDITOR_LOAD", false);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getEditorData: (state) => state.editorData,
    getEditorLoading: (state) => state.editorLoading,
  },
};
```

It seems only dragging labels works for moving stuff around but not like i'd expect. I think this makes sense but why can't I drag the body anywhere? It's not slotted in header or footer and the docs says that's the onlytime it wouldn't be? Can I not use  as the tag itself and drag it?

As I'm sure all of you can deduce the behavior I'm expecting, anything should be draggable into any section(in the future I want this to change so only cols can be dragged into rows, rows can only be dragged into sections etc(but for now I'm not sure how to do this so we start at the beginning :D)).

Also yes I know those components are kinda messy atm, until I fix this I'm not cleaning them up as I keep drastically changing the contents of these files trying to make it work, sorry it's hacky atm!

Any help or ideas would be amazing!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, first of all, a JS fiddle may have helped in debugging the code. I suggest start by adding a unique key and id on each `draggable` and `component-renderer` instance.

Comment: @Pontios I actually ended up getting this guy working, check this out: https://www.loom.com/share/22c6c3a8f929469e90e5839c22d2e6f9

If the code would help you or anyone else let me know and I will post the solution in a fiddle :)